# Azure remote debugging ports

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017

Im using VS2017, attempting to remotely debug an azure web application. What ports do i need to ask our IT admins to open on our corporate firewall in order to access the app?

Comment: This link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-app-service-environment-control-inbound-traffic) only mentions up to VS 2015. You can try with `4020` (which is for VS2015) or `4022` (each VS version's port gets increased by 2 :)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Gaurav** mentioned, you will have to open port **4022**. However you may also need to consider port **4023**. Here is a text from the following article 
[The Remote Debugger Port on 64-bit Operating Systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments#the-remote-debugger-port-on-64-bit-operating-systems)

> **The Remote Debugger Port on 64-bit Operating Systems**
>
> When the 64-bit version of the remote debugger is started, it uses the
>   **4022** port by default. If you debug a 32-bit process, the 64-bit
>   version of the remote debugger starts a 32-bit version of the remote
>   debugger on port **4023**. If you run the 32-bit remote debugger, it uses
>   **4022**, and **4023** is not used.

**More information:** [Configure the Windows Firewall for Remote Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/configure-the-windows-firewall-for-remote-debugging)